# Issue about "binary compatibility"

Tags: java, compatibility, binary-compatibility

When I read Java Language Specification (JLS8) > [Binary Compatibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13), one of a set changes that doesn't break binary compatibility is:

> Changing methods or constructors to return values on inputs for which they
>   previously either threw exceptions that normally should not occur or failed by
>   going into an infinite loop or causing a deadlock

I don't understand this idea.

Please help clarify and give an example to demonstrate it.

Comment: Here's the paper which the JLS refers to: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3a78/d9f53cf8e4b773466cac2482b7fd4228d9c5.pdf#page=8

Comment: The words 'for/of' don't appear in your quotation. Unclear what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Changing methods or constructors to return values on inputs for which
>   they previously either threw exceptions that normally should not occur

Existing code:

```
public int square(int x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return x * x;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot square odd numbers");
    }
}
```

Example of a compatible change that satisfies above rule:

```
public int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

Example of an incompatible change:

```
public int square(int x) {
    if (x % 2 == 1) {
        return x * x;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot square even numbers");
    }
}
```

> or failed by going into an infinite loop or causing a deadlock

Before:

```
public int square(int x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return x * x;
    } else {
        while (true)
            ;
    }
}
```

Example of a compatible change that satisfies above rule:

```
public int square(int x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return x * x;
    } else {
        // Even this is binary compatible (although bad form as the method
        // name is no longer self-explanatory.)
        return x * x * x;
    }
}
```

I think you get the picture.

The practical meaning of the statements is:

- You can *add* functionality that makes your method do something it couldn't do before successfully
- But you cannot *change* existing behaviour for already-valid inputs while remaining binary compatible.

It's a fancy way of saying something that make a lot of common sense.

Comment: I'm very confused. Your "compatible" change doesn't even compile and your "incompatible" change is fully binary compatible. What definition of compatibility are you working off?

Comment: The JLS is (intentionally?) vague on this point. They say they "support" the binary-compatible changes listed in the seminal paper on this topic. But Java also "supports" changes that are not binary-compatible according to that paper. The problem is that the change that the paper mentions can never by fully verified programmatically as that can be reduced to the halting problem. ("Changing methods or constructors to return values on inputs for which they previously either threw exceptions that normally should not occur or failed by going into an infinite loop or causing a deadlock.")

Comment: @shmosel see comment above, not sure if you get notified if I don't tag you

Comment: I'm not familiar with that paper, but here's the definition in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.2): "A change to a type is binary compatible with (equivalently, does not break binary compatibility with) pre-existing binaries if pre-existing binaries that previously linked without error will continue to link without error." There's no reason to expect a method's internal logic to affect linkage.

Comment: @shmosel It's in JLS Chapter 13 ([the link that the OP posted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13)). The question of the OP explicitly asks about that paper in the section that OP quoted. The OP quoted from the bulleted list in JLS Chapter 13, just below the section that reads  "Within the framework of Release-to-Release Binary Compatibility in SOM (Forman, Conner, Danforth, and Raper, Proceedings of OOPSLA '95), Java programming language binaries are binary compatible under all relevant transformations that the authors identify ".

Comment: @shmosel the OP didn't ask about linkage but about "one of a set changes that doesn't break binary compatibility" as defined in that seminal paper.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about it but what I can infer from it is this.

Suppose you had some method which would accept some integer and return some integer as a result.

```
int myMethod(int arg);
```

Now what JLS speaks is

> here is a list of some important binary compatible changes that the Java programming language supports:
>
> .....
> Changing methods or constructors to return values on inputs for which they previously either threw exceptions that normally should not occur or failed by going into an infinite loop or causing a deadlock.

Suppose for some invalid input (like your method was only designed to work on positive integers and you passed other than that), the method either throws some exception (either as a part of validation or otherwise) or it enters results into some undefined behavior like infinite loop etc.

So for these kinds of input (invalid input) if you want to return a value indicating the same then it does not break the binary compatibility is what the JLS is saying I think. Eg. you want to return -1 or something like that to indicate the passage of obsolete arguments (rather than throwing or having an undefined behavior). It's implementation specific and depends how you want to handle such inputs.

Comment: Why would one think otherwise? How is this different from any other change to a method's internals?

Comment: Me too, I also don't understand this change is how different with change method's internal?

Comment: @shmosel and John, method will still work the same way as it was working before for valid inputs(preserving binary compatibility). Answer by Erwin Bolwidt(https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934860/4041711) demonstrates the fact nicely.