# Ambigous about binary compatibility (release-to-release compatibility)

Tags: java, binary-compatibility

In the paper [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3a78/d9f53cf8e4b773466cac2482b7fd4228d9c5.pdf), one of the transformation without break the binary compatibility is:

> The domain of the procedure can be enlarged to return values for
>   inputs for which it previously aborted, failed to return (infinite
>   loop or deadlock)

I don't know clearly the exact idea that the authors want to describe.
If yes, please help me to clarify and please give an example to demonstrate.

Thank you for your help :)

In the JLS, I found the corresponding idea based on it:

> Changing methods or constructors to return values on inputs for which
>   they previously either threw exceptions that normally should not occur
>   or failed by going into an infinite loop or causing a deadlock

Comment: Are you in the same class as John Minverva? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930494/issue-about-binary-compatibility (3 hours ago) Your question is very vague - what is it that you don't understand about it and that you want clarification on?

Comment: I don't understand:

1. "return values for inputs" is "return value of methods", it's right?
2. what is the difference betweeb "enlarged to return values for inputs for which it previously aborted, failed to return (infinite loop or deadlock)" and "change the method's internal"?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) No real difference.  (The first statement probably implies the second one.)